# GAP code to get Multiplication Table.

Tags: computational-mathematics, gap, magma

I have a finite set $S=\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ and binary operation $\star$ on $S$ defined by

> $$x\star y= \left\{ \begin{array}{l l l}
> \frac{3(x+y)}{2} ~~\text{modulo} ~~n& \qquad \mbox{if $x$ and $y$ are odd.}\\
> x-y ~~\text{modulo} ~~n & \qquad \text{if $x+y$ is odd.}\\
> x\cdot y ~~\text{modulo} ~~n & \qquad \text{if $x$ and $y$ are even.}\\
> \end{array} \right.$$

I want to write GAP code to get Multiplication Table.

Comment: I don't think that the definition of the operation is consistent. How to calculate the result if one operand is odd and another is even? What to do if $n$ is even?

Comment: After defining the operation properly, the first task would be to write a GAP function which computes the product of $x$ and $y$: see [Functions](http://gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/tut/chap4.html) and [Programming Language](http://gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap4.html) chapters. Then for creating a table as a list of lists you may find useful hints in [Lists and Records](http://gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/tut/chap3.html) Chapter.

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake. I have corrected it.

Comment: Thanks - makes sense now. And BTW, if after creating a table you'd like to construct an algebraic structure given by this table, see [Magmas Defined by Multiplication Tables](http://gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap35.html#X782215B982F2F01C).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It largely writes itself.  First we define $\star$ as a function:

```
f:=function(x,y,n)
  if(x mod 2=1 and y mod 2=1) then
    return (3*(x+y)/2) mod n;
  elif((x+y) mod 2=1) then
    return (x-y) mod n;
  else
    return (x*y) mod n;
  fi;
end;;
```

We pick an $n$-value:

```
n:=10;;
```

Then the multiplication table can be computed using

```
M:=List([0..n-1],x->List([0..n-1],y->f(x,y,n)));
```

One warning about `M` though: GAP indices start at $1$ so `M[1][1]` returns the value of $0 \star 0$, etc.