# $R$ be a ring without identity. If $R$ has a maximal left ideal, then the Jacobson radical is still the intersection of all the maximal left ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gap, finite-rings, rngs

We know that the definition of the Jacobson radical $J(R)$

(a) in a ring $R$ with identity is: 
$$J(R)=\cap \mbox{ maximal left ideals}.$$

(b) in a ring $R$ without identity is: 
$$J(R)=\{a\in R\mid aR \mbox{ is right quasi regular}\}$$
$$=\{a\in R\mid \forall r\in R, \exists b\in R, \mbox{ such that }ar+b=arb\}$$

A natural guess is that if $R$ has a maximal left ideal $M$, 
even $R$ has no multiplicative identity, 
then the definition (a) coincides with the definition (b).
(I am not sure)

If my guess is correct,
then $\boldsymbol{J(R)\subseteq M}$.
But I found out a counterexample.
I use GAP to find a ring of order 8,
the command is: `ShowMultiplicationTable(SmallRing(8,37));`
The multiplication table of this ring as following figure.

There is a maximal left ideal $M=R(a+b)=\{0,a,b,a+b\}$
and the Jacobson radical of $R$ is $J(R)=\{0,a,c,a+c\}$.
Hence $\boldsymbol{J(R)\nsubseteq M=R(a+b)}$.

What did I do wrong?
Is there any book discuss this common mistakes?

```
gap> ShowMultiplicationTable(SmallRing(8,37));
*     | 0*a   c     b     b+c   a     a+c   a+b   a+b+c
------+------------------------------------------------
0*a   | 0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a  
c     | 0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a  
b     | 0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a   b     b     b     b    
b+c   | 0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a   b     b     b     b    
a     | 0*a   c     b     b+c   a+b   a+b+c a     a+c  
a+c   | 0*a   c     b     b+c   a+b   a+b+c a     a+c  
a+b   | 0*a   c     b     b+c   a     a+c   a+b   a+b+c
a+b+c | 0*a   c     b     b+c   a     a+c   a+b   a+b+c
```

Comment: By the way, you can copy and paste the text from the GAP window - please consider doing this next time. This will make the text searchable and will allow the reader to copy and paste GAP commands instead of retyping them. Also, if you indent code with four spaces, it will be displayed as code, e.g. like [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/874656/)

Comment: Thanks, I will indent the code next time.
But when I paste the output from the GAP,
it can not display normally.
Like this

Comment: *     | 0*a   c     b     b+c   a     a+c   a+b   a+b+c
------+------------------------------------------------
0*a   | 0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a
c     | 0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a
b     | 0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a   b     b     b     b
b+c   | 0*a   0*a   0*a   0*a   b     b     b     b
a     | 0*a   c     b     b+c   a+b   a+b+c a     a+c
a+c   | 0*a   c     b     b+c   a+b   a+b+c a     a+c
a+b   | 0*a   c     b     b+c   a     a+c   a+b   a+b+c
a+b+c | 0*a   c     b     b+c   a     a+c   a+b   a+b+c

Comment: Either looks like line endings conversion problem, unless this is just because this GAP output is in the comment, not in the question body. Try to paste into some text editor and then copy and paste to Math.SE from there.

Comment: Just edited it to show how this works.

Comment: Thank you about your guide,
wish you have a happy Mid-Autumn Festival.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $R=\mathbb{Z}$ but with zero multiplication. Then every element is quasiregular, so the radical is $R$. On the other hand, the intersection of the maximal ideals of $R$ is $\{0\}$.

The Jacobson radical is the intersection of the maximal *regular* left (or right) ideals. A left ideal $I$ is regular if there exists $e\in R$ such that $re-r\in I$, for all $r\in R$. It's obvious that no proper left ideal of a zero ring can be regular.

Comment: @egreg  Your definition of $J(R)$ is right but note that when $R$ is a ring with identity then $J(R)$ does equal to the intersection of all maximal left ideals of $R$. see [T.Y. Lam, A first course in Noncommutative Rings, p. 50]. The example you gave does not have multiplicative identity. (Comment posted as an answer by Alan Lao.)

Comment: @user26857 Yes, all is correct. But the question is about rings not necessarily with identity.